# Change count based on Filter in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

is there anyway to change the count in my tableau dashboard when I click filters?

This is about the total spent of the customers!  I have tons of customers and  have COUNTD formulas based on certain criterias and working well.

However, as part of the enhancement, we need to add this:

As we change the filter based on spent amount, the total count of customers should changed too.

Say:

1. We have January to December (as customers names) and along side, we have the type of spent and total spent.

Customer Name   TYPE    Total Spent
January INSURANCE   1,000
February    INSURANCE   100
March   RENT    150
April   RENT    300
May INSURANCE   450
June    CAR LOAN    359
July    CAR LOAN    1278
August  CAR LOAN    580
September   RENT    456
October INSURANCE   1,200
November    INSURANCE   100
December    INSURANCE   100

I have created a filter based on the range of spent ( 100 - 1500)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jif2Z.png)

Now, If the filter is set to ALL, then the total count of customers is 12.

If I change the filter to:

1. 100 - 500, the total count should be 8 ,
2. 500 - 1000 is 2, and
3. 1000 - 1500 count is 2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy8i8.png)

I tried using the FIXED function and cant seem to make it work.
Hope someone can enlighten me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If using a FIXED this calculates BEFORE filters are applied, so filters don't alter the numbers. To rectify this add your filters to Context. In Context the filter calculates before the FIXED.

Check the Tableau order of operations, which may help you better understand this. https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/order_of_operations.htm